# Bokeh doesn't find Bar-chart modules on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bokeh, raspberry-pi3

_I'm trying to make bar-charts with Bokeh to be outputted as .html-files. Everything works fine with simple plotting, but for some reason when i try to run the following code:

```
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df

p = Bar(df, label='yr', values='mpg', agg='mean',
    title="Average MPG by YR")

output_file("bar.html")_
```

I end up with an error saying:

> ImportError: No module named 'bokeh.charts'

I have installed Pandas, Numpy through pip and they all can be found using the help('modules') command. I've understood that Pandas is required for high-level Bokeh charts and it's been installed through Pip

Pandas version: 0.20.3
Bokeh version: 0.12.9
Python is version 3.4.2

I've tried also different import commands, "from bokeh import *" etc. but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Holoviews](http://holoviews.org/), if you just need simple bar charts, these are also now easy to make from the stable [`bokeh.plotting` API](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html), e.g.:

```
group = df.groupby('cyl')
source = ColumnDataSource(group)

cyl_cmap = factor_cmap('cyl', palette=Spectral5, factors=sorted(df.cyl.unique()))

p = figure(plot_height=350, x_range=group, title="MPG by # Cylinders")

p.vbar(x='cyl', top='mpg_mean', width=1, source=source,
       line_color=cyl_cmap, fill_color=cyl_cmap)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem, Bokeh own tutorials still point out to this deprecated version, they should get them fixed.

Comment: They should all be updated, can you point me to specific links that are out of date?

Answer (score 0):

`bokeh.charts` has been [deprecated](https://blog.bokeh.org/posts/release-0-12-6). You can get back the functionality by installing and importing the bkcharts package but this won’t be supported in the future. Bokeh devs recommend checking [holoviews](https://holoviews.org/) (which use bokeh as a possible back-end)